Looking for the name of a SF or horror movie - bunker spreading vine/fungus
I am looking for the title of a movie.  This is what I remember from it...
This man shows up at a bunker that is about to be destroyed.  The military is closing up everything.  A man in a wheelchair is suffering bedsores, but wants to complete his duty at the bunker.  They find this room that had been closed up and open a sealed container.  A vine/fungus/plant spreads out of it and disentegrates everything it touches.  The man in the wheelchair tries to climb a ladder up but does not make it out, but his wife does.  This plant/vine/fungus stops everything live in its path...kind of paralyzes and maybe disentegrates it or turns it to ash (can't remember)
The two end up at a church were an indian and his young relative son? know about the spreading vine/fungus/plant.  The spreading vine/fungus chases them out of there.
The man tried to warn them about the sealed up room.  Come to find out, his mother and father worked there at the military bunker when he was a young child. The mother carved into his hand the number of the bunker room before she killed herself and her husband telling the boy to never forget that number.

Sounds like Living Hell, (2008):

In 1969, ten-year-old Frank Sears is confronted by his hysterical
  mother Eleanore, who carves the message "S3 V12" into the palms of his
  hands with a pencil and warns him to never forget her warning before
  murdering her husband and committing suicide.

And:

They discover a man's corpse with evidence of disease inside, but when
  Carrie attempts to biopsy the infected tissue, the infection comes
  alive in the form of giant, rapidly-growing plantlike roots. Struss is
  immediately killed when he tries to bolt the tank closed, and the
  organism grows out of the room in moments.

